# Driver from Node.js to Mongodb on Windows

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I've not been able to find a native Mongodb driver for Node.js on Windows.

I'm using native Node.js and Mongodb on my Windows box. Both are running fine.

Would anyone know how to get Node.js and Mongo to talk natively on Windows?

Comment: I doubt a native driven exists. Windows support is very experimental. Windows won't get npm until christmas. I recommend you go back to unix until 0.6 comes out

Answer (score -1):

well try it http://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/ and this reference i hope will help u 2 - http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb and even this http://howtonode.org/node-and-mongo

Comment: yes, indeed, there is no native Windows support for node and etc. however, it doesn't mean that u can't use it on Windows with stuff like node-mongodb-native, for example